# Android can't send PrintWriter message twice in socket with Java. It is also possible instead of sending me a Java code to send a Python code

Tags: java, python, android-studio, sockets

I created a code that sends commands to a server I wrote using Python. The code only works once (the server receives what I sent the first time) but the second time it seems that nothing is sent because the server does not receive new information it keeps waiting for new information. My code:

```
    StringBuilder Data = new StringBuilder(); // The Data to send

    public void Send(View view) {
        Thread send = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Socket socket = new Socket("20.7.65.2", 6398); // Create connection to the server
                    OutputStream output = socket.getOutputStream(); // Get the key to output to server

                    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(output, true);
                    writer.println(Data.toString()); // Send the data

                    Data.setLength(0); // Delete "Data" contant


                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        send.start();
    }

    public void Continue(View view) { 
        Data.append("Hello from client"); // Append to "Data"

        Send(null); // Run the send functionn (again)

    }


    }
```

My Python Server:

```
import socket, time

soc = socket.socket()
soc.bind((socket.gethostname(), 6398))

soc.listen(5)
(client, (ipNum, portNum)) = soc.accept()


print("Client connected")

while True:
    message = client.recv(1024).decode()

    if(message != ""):
        print(message)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

**In short, I try to run the run function twice. The first time it sends to the server and it receives the information, and the second time the server is still waiting for the information and not receiving what I sent again. Maybe it's because he's not available to receive all messages sent to him from all clients**

**It is also possible instead of sending me a Java code to send a Python code that will work and receive all messages from all clients**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, the server is only accepting a cnnection once and then it recieves from same client. But according to your question, I think your server should be able to listen to mulitple clients hence, you could use multithreading in the server. Instead of threading the client, I used button which when clicked connects with server. I also can't understand the need of threading the client. If you think, some changes are required in the answer, you could comment.

this is python server

```
import socket, time
import threading

soc = socket.socket()
# print(socket.)
soc.bind(("192.168.1.5", 6398))

soc.listen(5)

def info(client):
    message = client.recv(1024).decode()
    if(message != ""):
        print(message)
    return

while True:
    (client, (ipNum, portNum)) = soc.accept()
    print("Client connected")
    threading.Thread(target=info,args=(client,)).start()
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    StringBuilder Data = new StringBuilder(); // The Data to send
    private Button btn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn= findViewById(R.id.connectBtn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Continue();
            }
        });
    }


    public void Send() {
        Thread send = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.1.5", 6398); // Create connection to the server
                    OutputStream output = socket.getOutputStream(); // Get the key to output to server

                    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(output, true);
                    writer.println(Data.toString()); // Send the data

                    Data.setLength(0); // Delete "Data" contant


                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        send.start();
    }

    public void Continue() {
            Data.append("Hello from client"); // Append to "Data"

            Send(); // Run the send functionn (again)
    }

}
```

Don't forget to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` in the **AndroidManifest.xml**.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/connectBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Wait a  minute please

Comment: Hey, a little tip: use ```writer.flush(); ```

Comment: isn't that autoflush to be true?